# Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type - office365

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, office365

I have the following code for sending email using codeigniter email library using SMTP using office365 SMTP

```
  $this->load->library('email');
  $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
  $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.office365.com';
  $config['smtp_user'] = 'xxxxxx@example.com';
  $config['smtp_pass'] = '123456';

  $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
  $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
  $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
  $config['smtp_port'] = 587;
  $config['smtp_timeout'] = 60;
  $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
  $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
  $this->email->initialize($config);

  $this->email->from('xxxxxx@example.com');
  $this->email->to('test123@gmail.com');

  $this->email->subject('Email Test');
  $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
  $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
  $this->email->send();
```

And it shows an error

> Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized
>   authentication type [SG2PR0601CA0010.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com] 
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.

In office365,shows configuration like bellow
[image]

**NOTE**: It is using office365 SMTP not gmail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279831/failed-to-send-auth-login-command-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @Artier It is not gmail,it is office365.read the question prperly

Comment: @Shijin did you found solution I'm facing same issue.

Comment: @RavK  No,we have changed mail to gmail

Answer (score 0):

Just use this line of code in your config file code:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
instead of
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
```

Hopefully, it will solve the error.

Comment: Why should this solve the error?